# Merging two txt files based on a common column by awk

Tags: awk

I would like to merge two files based on the matching column by using awk

b.txt(separated by tabs)

```
A
B
C
D
C
C
E
G
```

a.txt(separated by tabs)

```
1       2       2       4       19      A
2       2       3       3       12      B
3       2       9       2       5       C
4       3       8       0       9       D
5       5       4       1       1       E
```

Then i run the script

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {if (NR==FNR) {a[$NF]=$0; next} if ($NF in a) {print a[$1]}}' a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

I get the c.txt like this

```
1   2   2   4   19  A
2   2   3   3   12  B
3   2   9   2   5   C
4   3   8   0   9   D
3   2   9   2   5   C
3   2   9   2   5   C
5   5   4   1   1   E
```

Actually,my desired output is

```
1   2   2   4   19  A
2   2   3   3   12  B
3   2   9   2   5   C
4   3   8   0   9   D
3   2   9   2   5   C
3   2   9   2   5   C
5   5   4   1   1   E
                    G
```

or

```
A   1   2   2   4   19  
B   2   2   3   3   12  
C   3   2   9   2   5   
D   4   3   8   0   9   
C   3   2   9   2   5   
C   3   2   9   2   5   
E   5   5   4   1   1   
G
```

Aany suggestions for me? appreciate it！

Comment: `awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[$NF]=$0; next} { if ($NF in a) {print a[$1]} else print $1}}' a.txt b.txt > c.txt`. I've added `else` part to your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of tweaks, both the desired results can be obtained from your well made attempt. To get the first desired result,

```
awk -F"\t" '
  BEGIN { OFS = FS } 
  NR == FNR { a[$NF] = $0; pos = NF; next }
  { if ( $NF in a ) { $NF = a[$1]; } else { $pos = $1; $1 = ""; } } 1
' a.txt b.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `csvjoin`:

```
$ csvjoin -H --tabs --left -c 1,6 b.txt a.txt | csvformat -K 1 -T
```

`-H`: The input `tsv` file has no header row.

`--tsbs` or `-t`: The input file is `tab` delimited.

`--left` performs full outer join.

`-c 1,6` join by column 1 of first file with column 6 of second file.

`csvformat` options:

`-K 1` removes first header row added by `csvjoin` command.

`-T` changes delimiter from `comma` to `tab`.